# Can't connect to with TP-LINK USB wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, adapter

My notebook's internal WIFI adapter stopped working (maybe because of overheating?).
I bought a USB WIFI (TP-LINK 150Mbs Wireless N USB Adapter TL-WN723N).  Now internet is fine in Windows 7.

But not in Ubuntu I think it's still trying to use the internal adapter. (Atheros)

Can I disable the internal adapter and get Ubuntu to use the USB WIFI?

It's a bit of a pain to fix 'cos I have to reboot between Windows with internet and Ubuntu with no internet...

Comment: Please add the Version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this terminal command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Find your internal (Atheros??) device and find its driver. It may be ath9k or ath5k or similar. Now blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath9k" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
exit
```

Of course, substitute the driver you found, if not ath9k. If in doubt, stop and ask here.

Comment: the internal driver came back, so I followed your instructions, now it's working perfectly thanks.